# Installing lscpu utility on Redhat 5.11

Tags: linux, rhel-5

I am using Redhat 5.11.

I require an utility 'lscpu' which comes with "util-linux" package from version 2.15 (read somewhere on Internet).
The max version of util-linux package that is supported by 5.x RHEL is 2.13.

I need to upgrade this package to 2.15 or latest, since my application depends on lscpu utility.
Please suggest if there is anyway I can upgrade "util-linux" package?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you use the information in `/proc/cpuinfo` instead? `lscpu` will not give you any more data than is in there. You could even write a `lscpu` script to hack it into the format you need.

Comment: At the moment, I wrote a script to imitate lscpu o/p format from /proc/cpuinfo and using that.

I am looking for a way to avoid this bypass, as I have to package the app with lscpu related lib for distribute.

Comment: I have taken the source and upgraded the package.